# JInternalFrame and JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have `master employee` form and I want to show em on my `main form`. That `main form` is MDI container, so I just want to know how to show the `master employee` form.

Here is the`JDesktopPane` creating object code:

```
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();
LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
/** Creates new form MainForm */
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
}
```

And here is to call `masteremployee form` though it's not working.

```
  MasterEmployee me = new MasterEmployee();       
    desk.add(me);
    me.setVisible(true);
```

How do I resolve this ?
I want to make the `master employee` form shows on Jdesktoppane

### Update:

It is working now. I used the [following](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) reference.

Comment: What's not working? What is "this"?

Comment: @JoshM i want to make the master employee form shows on Jdesktoppane

Comment: @Cignitor, so did you read the tutorial???

Comment: i am reading on it, it seems the tutorial give me another confusion

Comment: `yap it is working now. i used the following reference.` - then you should accept the answer that helped you so people know the problem has been solved. Also, stating the code your forgot would be helpful to other people who read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for a working example that shows you how to create and select an internal frame.

You need to do more than just invoke setVisible() on the internal frame and I have no idea what the code in your MasterEmployess class does.